# Solving the integral $\int_{c}^{\frac{x}{i}+c}\int_{(i-1)z}^{x+ic-z}[x-(i-1)z]^{i-2}e^{-x-z}\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dz$

Tags: integration

I have following integral to solve

$$\int_{c}^{\frac{x}{i}+c}\int_{(i-1)z}^{x+ic-z}[x-(i-1)z]^{i-2}e^{-x-z} \,\mathrm dx \,\mathrm dz$$

where $i$ is positive integer and $c>0$. After doing some manipulation I was able to simplify it to following form

$$K\left[e^{-ic}[1-e^{-x}]-e^{-x-ic}\int_0^{x}\sum_{j=0}^{i-2}\frac{z^j}{j!}\,\mathrm dz\right]$$

where $K$ is some constant. I do not know how to simplify the last integral. However, if somebody has another way of solving it then please help me.

Comment: I think we can change the order of integration and summation and then the solution will be $K\left[e^{-ic}[1-e^{-x}]-e^{-x-ic}\sum_{j=0}^{i-2}\frac{x^{j+1}}{(j+1)!}\right]$.